# Only render&simulate some of the objects in python

Tags: rendering, materials, rigid-body-simulation

I have a question: Now I have a giant amount of objects as well as the materials, however, I only want to select some of them to participate in the simulation&rendering every time(which means the objects will be used multiple times), what should I do to speed up this process as fast as possible?(such as how to prevent other objects from slowing down the speed of simulation&rendering of the selected objects?)

Comment: I think I know what you mean but can you be a little more specific? Do you want the objects that are simulated to be visible in the render or only the ones during simulation to be visible?

Comment: @TheJeran, thanks for your attention. Well, I want the selected objects to be visible and rigid ones to participate in the physics simulation process.
After baking the physics simulations I will render each frame. And I only want the selected objects to be visible in the rendering results.

Comment: Okay so if I'm understanding correctly. You want to have something interact with a physics simulation. Then hide the simulated objects for the render?

Comment: No, maybe I should give an example: If there are 1000 objects in total, and I just want to select 10 of them out to do simulation and rendering, while the rest 990 objects should not participate in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Oh I just re-read the title and saw you meant python. Sorry
In that case add your items to cooresponding collections and then

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].rigidbody_world.collection = pointer


bpy.data.collections['Hidden'].hide_render = True
```

Alright, so the easiest way to partition and omit certain objects is through collections.

First select the objects you want either through random deselect or random select.

[image]

Here I've selected 10 random objects.

I then add those to a collections (Press M)

[image]

I then hide those (uncheck the box)
[image]

and select the others and add to a new collection.
[image]

Then you check accordingly
[image]

Then in your rigidbody world change the simulation to visible

[image]

Note: Everything you want to interact with the simulation needs to be in that collection.

For rendering, if a collection is unchecked it wont show in render.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and detailed explanations. I will have a try right now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your method, it works! Such an elegant method!

Comment: Hi, recently I have met a new problem. There are two ways to turn one object into rigid one, the first one, as you have mentioned, link the object into the rigidbody collection, and the another one is by using commend: "bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add({'object': blender_object})", however, the former one is much faster than the later, I wonder what causes this problem.   And it seems that, the former one will result in the problem of "the scale is not applied to the object", further affecting the result of simulation.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you are trying to accomplish. But I have to imagine it's because one is simply linking two data objects and the other is running an operation.

try the bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add (note the S at the end) if you are able to select multiple objects. Should be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will have a try!